# How do I get a sensible text representation of the exception passed to a __exit__ method?

Tags: python

I have a Python class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods for use with the `with` statement. One of the things the `__exit__` method does is close a log file:

```py
def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
     [...]
     self.log_file.write('Exiting')
     self.log_file.close()
```

I would like the "Exiting" message to log why it is exiting. For example, if a division by zero occurs, I'd like the output to be this (or something similar that conveys the same information; doesn't have to be identical format)

```
Exiting due to ZeroDivisionError: Division by zero
```

Based on [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/traceback.html), I tried this, assuming that the `traceback` parameter passed to `__exit__` is a TracebackException object

```py
    self.log_file.write(f'Exiting due to {traceback.format_exception_only()}')
```

but I get `AttributeError: 'traceback' object has no attribute 'format_exception_only'`, so presumably my assumption was wrong, and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: @quamrana I have no idea. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) say "If an exception caused the suite to be exited, its type, value, and traceback are passed as arguments to `__exit__()`", but it's not clear to me what format those things are in. I took a guess at it being a [TracebackException](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/traceback.html#tracebackexception-objects) from the built-in traceback library but apparently that was wrong.

Comment: I'm also struggling to find what a traceback object is, but the `exception_value` parameter might have what you are looking for,

Comment: [Here's](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#traceback-objects) the documentation for traceback objects. `TracebackException` is a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `traceback.print_tb()` function

```
from traceback import print_tb
print_tb(traceback_object, max_frames, file)
```

Args 2 and 3 are optional; if ommitted the *entire* stacktrace will be printed to `sys.stderr`

```
print_tb(traceback_object)
```